# Eclipse will not read/run fxml files

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am coding in Eclipse, and am attemtping to use both, javafx, fxml ad CSS to create a MAd Libs game for my final project in my java class. I have installed the latest version of scene builder from gluon, as well as the latest JRE from java. This is the code I have

```
package application;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.ResourceBundle;

  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
  import javafx.event.EventHandler;
  import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
  import javafx.scene.Parent;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

  public class Main extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scenebuilder.fxml"));
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Shane Ramos Final Project");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
        } 
    }
```

Whenever I try to run it (have it call on my fxml file) it gives me this error log in the console.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:21)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this and am at a total loss. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is scenebuilder.fmxl in the same package as Main?

Comment: yes i believe that it is

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a location first:

For example:

`private Parent root;`

`...`

`FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();`
`loader.setLocation(YourClass.class.getResource("yourFile.fxml"));`

`root = (Parent) loader.load();`

And make sure that your fxml file is in the right folder.

According to your code, your fxml file and your Main.java should be in the same folder on the system.